# CSS positioning error, relative to absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm crap with css. 

I began building a page with the body set to `absolute`, and build all elements around this.
When the browser zoom changes, the positioning goes & nothing looks correct (only correct @ 100% ).

I changed the body to be `relative` and re-structed so the main divs that build up the page are running off of the body.

However, it seems I've truly funked this one.
nearly all elelments hide away when updating the body to be `relative`, even though I understand absolute & relative to work together (parent/child).

ScreenShots:
(Should Look like this (all position absolute))
[image]

[image]
(The issue I'm trying to resolve. zooming in/out causes the tabs to move up/down (above & below))

[image]

(This is when I set body to relative, yes, that's the whole page shot.(below))

[image]

**css:**

```
        body{
                position: relative; 
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                //font-family: Arial;
                zoom: 100%;
            }

        #invoiceOptions{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9dede;
            top: 11.9%;
            left: 10%;
            width: 80%;
            height: 33.5%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-size: 15pt;
        }

        #referals{
            position: absolute;
            //background-color: #C93939;
            top: 11.9%; //11
            left: 10%;
            width: 80%;
            height: 33.5%;
            font-size: 15pt;
            border-radius: 1%;
        }

        #orders{
            position: absolute;
            //background-color: #C93939;
            //background-image: url('background.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            top:11.9%;
            left:10%;
            width: 80%;
            height: 75%;
            border-radius: 1%;
            font-size: 15pt;

            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;

        }
        #orders:hover{
            overflow-y: visible;


        }
        #toolbar{
           position: absolute;

            background-color: white;
            width: 80%;
            left: 8%;
            height: 20%;
            border-radius: 5px;

        }
        #border1{
             position: absolute;
             width: 10%;
             height: 100%;
             background-color: black;
             //same for border2, but on right.
       }
        .tab-links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 40%;
            top: 28.5%;
            left: 3%;
            background: no-repeat;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        }
```

**html.**

```
<body>
            <div id="toolbar">
                <div style="">

                    <h4 style="position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 15%;">Welcome <?php echo $User[0]; ?>!</h4>

                        <ul class="tab-links">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Orders <div id='orderCount' style='display: inline;'></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2">Referrals <div id='referralCount' style='display: inline;'></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab3">Options</a></li>
                        </ul>


                    <div style="">
                    <a href="https://XXXXXXXX.com/mysagepay/" target="_blank">
                        <IMG style="position: absolute; border-radius: 5%; left: 60%;" border=0 alt=SagePay src="https://live.sagepay.com/mysagepay/images/sagepay_logo.png" width=136 height=50>
                    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <A href="https://www.businessexpress-uk.com/" target="_blank">
                        <IMG style="position: absolute; border-radius: 5%; left: 70%;" border=0 alt=SagePay src="https://XXXX.com/Content/images/logo.png" width=140 height=50>
                    </A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <A href="http://XXXXX.co.uk/support/staff/" target="_blank">
                        <IMG style="position: absolute; border-radius: 5%; left: 80%;" border=0 alt=Fusion src="http://XXXXX.co.uk/support/__swift/themes/__cp/images/fusion.gif" width=200 height=50>
                    </A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                    <div id="orders">

                        <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                            <table width="100%" class='table'>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Customer</b></td>
                                        <td><b>Company</b></td>
                                        <td>User ID</td>
                                        <td><b>Time</b>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="orderBody">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div id="orderHolder"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="print">
                        <a href="PrintAllWelcomeLetters.php"><img src="print.png" title="Print All Invoices"/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="tab2" class="tab">

                    <div id="referals">

                        <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                            <table width='100%' class='table'>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Account</b></td>
                                        <td><b>Customer</b></td>
                                        <td><b>Referral ID</b></td>
                                        <td><b>UUID</b></td>
                                        <td><b>Time</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody id="tbody">
                                </tbody>

                            </table> 

                            <div id="hold"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                    <div id="invoiceOptions">

                        <div id="DisplayOptions">
                            <fieldset style="width: 100%;">

                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>  

        <div id='border1'></div>
        <div id='border2'></div>
    </body>
```

**Notes.**

I'm using ajax to populate a web-gen table. I've excluded the table css for now, however comment if required & I will include


**update.**

I've included `tab-links` into the css. this is the css for the holder of the tab buttons (grey). The tab buttons themselves are floated left.

the table contents, is a styleless div contaings the 3 tab option contents (referral, order & options).

Comment: Try removing positioning from your body alltogether

Comment: that solves half the issue, cheers :) the main & original issue of the gap between table & tabs on zoom is bugging me.

Comment: You are using a lot of absolutely positioned elements. You are going to want to avoid that whenever possible because those elements can fly out everywhere and their children tend not to behave all the time.

Comment: i wasn't joking when I said I was crap at css. I spend ages understanding it, get good, then hit a wall of errors & I'm back to square one.